# Is there a way to configure postfix to bypass spam/RBL checks on a particular destination hostname or username?

Tags: postfix, rbl

I'm running Postfix on CentOS 7, a fairly generic implementation, but I do employ some RBL checking on incoming mail.  I like using SORBS for example but I have a few clients who seem to have issues with senders being in their list.  Is there any way to map a specific hostname to bypass RBL checks but otherwise keep them in place for everybody else?

Comment: You can achieve the same using postfix [restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) provided your RBL checks are happening in `smtpd_*_restrictions`